# Retrieve Outlook logged-in user SMTP address after connecting through OLE

Tags: delphi, outlook, delphi-xe2, ole

[Exchange Web Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/bb408417%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx) has a [ResolveNames()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/aa563518%28v=exchg.140%29.aspx) function that I can use to retrieve (among other things) the primary SMTP address for the Active Directory user that logged on to Exchange Server through EWS.

I am now programming through OLE against Outlook and would like the same functionality.

I have been browsing through the [Outlook object model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866465.aspx) but can't find an appropriate object or method.

Does anyone know of an object/method that I can use to get the primary SMTP address?

Below is the current Delphi code that I use to connect to Outlook.
 
For the default user logging in (AUserSMTP='') it returns the OutlookApp COM Object (through GetActiveOleObject or CreateOleObject), a [NameSpace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb219955%28v=office.12%29.aspx) (through GetNameSpace) and a [Folder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb219900%28v=office.12%29.aspx) (through GetDefaultFolder) object, but I could not find where to go from there.
I thought lNameSpace.CurrentUser (a [Recipient object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb219964%28v=office.12%29.aspx)) might lead somewhere, but its Address property only returns a string like *'/o=TimeTell/ou=Exchange Administrative Group (FYDIBOHF23SPDLT)/cn=Recipients/cn=developer'* without email address...

Any suggestions about the route to take?

```
function TDataModuleSyncOutlook.ConnectToOutlook(AUserSMTP: String = ''): Boolean;
var
   lNameSpace, lRecipient: OleVariant;
begin
   Result      := false;
   FWasCreated := False;  
   try
      FOutlookApp := GetActiveOleObject(scxOutlookApp);
      Result := True;
   except
      try
         FOutlookApp := CreateOleObject(scxOutlookApp);
         FWasCreated := True;
         Result := True;
      except
         on E:Exception do ...
      end;
   end;
   if Result then      
   begin
      lNameSpace := FOutlookApp.GetNameSpace(scxNameSpace);
      if AUserSMTP <> '' then   // This part not applicable to the question   
      begin   // Open shared calendar als er een expliciete gebruiker is opgegeven...
         lRecipient := lNameSpace.CreateRecipient(AUserSMTP);
         try
            FCalendarFolder := lNameSpace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(lRecipient, olFolderCalendar);
         except
            on E:Exception do ...
         end;
      end
      else   // ... anders de default calendar folder openen
         FCalendarFolder := lNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar);
   end;
   FOleInitialized := Result;
   if Result then TSyncLogger.LogAlways('Connected to Outlook') else TSyncLogger.LogAlways('Connection to Outlook failed');
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `Application.Session.CurrentUser.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser.PrimarySmtpAddress` (you would of course need to check for nulls).

As for the account order, you can either use Extended MAPI and IOlkAccountManager.GetOrder (you can play with that object in [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy/) (I am its author) if you click IOlkAccountManager button) or you can use [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/) (I am also its author) and its `RDOSession.Accounts.GetOrder` method (see http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOAccounts.htm). The first account in the returned collection will be the default one.

Comment: Thanks, now using
  if VarIsClear(FOutlookApp.Session)
  or VarIsClear(FOutlookApp.Session.CurrentUser)
  or VarIsClear(FOutlookApp.Session.CurrentUser.AddressEntry)
  or VarIsClear(FOutlookApp.Session.CurrentUser.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser)
  or VarIsClear(FOutlookApp.Session.CurrentUser.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser.PrimarySmtpAddress)
  begin
     LogError(...
     DisConnectFromOutlook;
     Exit;
  end
  else
     lLoginSMTP := FOutlookApp.Session.CurrentUser.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser.PrimarySmtpAddress;

Comment: Ouch! That is not very efficient... Multiple dot notation is never a good idea in COM...

Comment: Yeah, you're right, I better clean that up a little, since they're all OLEVariant in Delphi I can just reassign these: Var := FOutlookApp.Session, Var := Var.CurrentUser, ...

Answer (score 0):

I found it. I have to go through the Accounts object in the namespace:

```
for i := 1 to lNameSpace.Accounts.Count do
   if lNameSpace.Accounts.Item[i].AccountType = olExchange then
   begin
      lAccount := lNameSpace.Accounts.Item[i];
      Break;
   end;
if VarIsClear(lAccount) then
begin
   DisConnectFromOutlook;
   Exit;
end;
lLoginSMTP := lAccount.SmtpAddress;
```

The only thing I would still like is to [determine the default account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18058224/how-can-i-determine-the-default-outlook-account).