# Does Folder.Items.Add always add to the front of the Items array?

Tags: delphi, calendar, outlook, ole

In my (Delphi) code I create a new calendar appointment in Outlook:

```
function TDataModuleSyncOutlook.ExportEventToOutlook(AOutlookEvent: TcxSchedulerEvent; var AOutlookEntryID: String): Boolean;
var
  AAppointmentItem: OleVariant;
begin
  Result := false;
  AAppointmentItem := FCalendarFolder.Items.Add(olAppointmentItem);
  ...
  AAppointmentItem.Save;  // This generates AAppointmentItem.EntryID 
  AOutlookEntryID := AAppointmentItem.EntryID;
  ...
```

I want to maintain a list of EntryIDs pointing to the index in FCalendarFolder.Items[].

Running the code I noticed that the new item is added to the front of Items, i.e. it is FCalendarFolder.Items[1] (Items is 1-based).

My question is: **Is this guaranteed to be the case?**, i.e. does FCalendarFolder.Items.Add always add the new appointment in FCalendarFolder.Items[1]?
Because if it's not, how can I couple the EntryIDs to the index?'

If this is not guaranteed how do I maintain that cross-reference? I see no other way:

- It does not seem that an [AppointmentItem object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn320241%28v=office.15%29.aspx) has a .Index or .ItemIndex property
- Looking up an Item by EntryID, using either [Items.Find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869662%28v=office.15%29.aspx) or [Items.Restrict](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869597%28v=office.15%29.aspx) is explicitly not supported for EntryID

*Background*:
FCalendarFolder was retrieved with either GetDefaultFolder or GetSharedDefaultFolder as:
(code based on [Retrieve Outlook logged-in user SMTP address after connecting through OLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18053110/retrieve-outlook-logged-in-user-smtp-address-after-connecting-through-ole/))

```
const
  olFolderCalendar  = $00000009;  // Outlook default calendar folder
  olAppointmentItem = $00000001;
  scxOutlookApp     = 'outlook.application';
  scxNameSpace      = 'MAPI';

function TDataModuleSyncOutlook.ConnectToOutlook(AUserSMTP: String = ''): Boolean;
var
   lNameSpace,                   
   lRecipient,
   lVar      : OleVariant;
   lLoginSMTP: String;
begin
   Result      := false;
   FWasCreated := False;  
   try
      FOutlookApp := GetActiveOleObject(scxOutlookApp);         // Application object
      Result := True;
   except
      try
         FOutlookApp := CreateOleObject(scxOutlookApp);
         FWasCreated := True;
         Result := True;
      except
         on E:Exception do TSyncLogger.LogError(E.Message);
      end;
   end;
   if Result then         
   begin
      lNameSpace := FOutlookApp.GetNamespace(scxNameSpace);
      lVar := FOutlookApp.Session;                                   // NameSpace object for the current session
      if not VarIsClear(lVar) then lVar := lVar.CurrentUser;         // Recipient object for the currently logged-on user
      if not VarIsClear(lVar) then lVar := lVar.AddressEntry;        // AddressEntry object for the recipient
      if not VarIsClear(lVar) then lVar := lVar.GetExchangeUser;     // Returns an ExchangeUser object that represents the AddressEntry
      if not VarIsClear(lVar) then lVar := lVar.PrimarySmtpAddress;  // String representing the SMTP address for the ExchangeUser
      if not VarIsClear(lVar) then
         lLoginSMTP := FOutlookApp.Session.CurrentUser.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser.PrimarySmtpAddress;
      else 
         LogError(...)
      if LowerCase(AUserSMTP) <> Lowercase(lLoginSMTP) then
      begin   // Open shared calendar if it's a different user
         lRecipient := lNameSpace.CreateRecipient(AUserSMTP);
         try
            FCalendarFolder := lNameSpace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(lRecipient, olFolderCalendar);
         except
            on E:Exception do
            begin
               Result := false;
               LogError(...);
            end;
         end;
      end
      else   // ... otherwise open default calendar folder 
      begin
         FCalendarFolder := lNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar);
      ...
```

Comment: A side note: if you import Outlook typelib, you'll get a much cleaner code w/o those `OleVariant` all around.

Comment: @Free That would've been clearer, yes. The code was largely copied from others so we decided to leave the late binding instead of rewriting everything for early binding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolutely not. There is no order at all unless you explicitly sort the Items collection using Items.Sort. If you know the entry id, you can reopen the item using Namespace.GetItemFromID.