# Starting Outlook from code, then manually, gives category name mismatches

Tags: delphi, outlook, delphi-xe2, ole, outlook-2007

1. If I start Outlook manually and then run my program that talks to it through OLE, all my (renamed) categories with colors are visible:

[image]

2. If I do not start Outlook manually, but have it startup from code, **then** start it up manually *as well*, I suddenly miss my renamed category info:

[image]

In an individual appointment we see that the renamed categories still exist:

[image]

but the link between these category names and some 'master list' (?) that defines the colors seems to be missing.

**Luckily** my code does not seem to have a problem, the categories it retrieves for an appointment are the renamed ones.

But I would like to change the behavior under point 2 - when my program is running and I open Outlook it's very nice for debugging if I see the correct data in Outlook ;-)

Here is the code that starts Outlook:

```
function TDataModuleSyncOutlook.ConnectToOutlook(AUserSMTP: String = ''): Boolean;
var
   lRecipient,
   lVar      : OleVariant;
   lLog,
   lLoginSMTP: String;
begin
   Result      := false;
   FWasCreated := False;  // Breakpoint 'Ignore subsequent exceptions'
   try
      FOutlookApp := GetActiveOleObject(scxOutlookApp);         // Application object. This code fails if Outlook is not yet running...
      Result := True;
   except
      try
         FOutlookApp := CreateOleObject(scxOutlookApp);         // ... and then this creates the Outlook instance 
         FWasCreated := True;
         Result := True;
      except
         on E:Exception do TSyncLogger.LogError(E.Message);
      end;
   end;
   if Result then          // Breakpoint 'Handle subsequent exceptions'
   begin
      FNameSpace := FOutlookApp.GetNamespace(scxNameSpace);
      // Oplossing uit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18053110/retrieve-outlook-logged-in-user-smtp-address-after-connecting-through-ole/
      lVar := FOutlookApp.Session;                                   // NameSpace object for the current session
      if not VarIsClear(lVar) then lVar := lVar.CurrentUser;         // Recipient object for the currently logged-on user
      if not VarIsClear(lVar) then lVar := lVar.AddressEntry;        // AddressEntry object for the recipient
      if not VarIsClear(lVar) then lVar := lVar.GetExchangeUser;     // Returns an ExchangeUser object that represents the AddressEntry
      if not VarIsClear(lVar) then lVar := lVar.PrimarySmtpAddress;  // String representing the SMTP address for the ExchangeUser
      if not VarIsClear(lVar) then
      begin
         lLoginSMTP := FOutlookApp.Session.CurrentUser.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser.PrimarySmtpAddress;
         TSyncLogger.LogDetail('Primary Exchange SMTP address detected as: ' + lLoginSMTP);
      end
      else
      begin
         TSyncLogger.LogError(sErrNoExchangeAccount);
         DisConnectFromOutlook;
         Exit;
      end;
      if LowerCase(AUserSMTP) <> Lowercase(lLoginSMTP) then
      begin   // Open shared calendar for different user. This does not apply in my test case
         lRecipient := FNameSpace.CreateRecipient(AUserSMTP);
         try
            FCalendarFolder := FNameSpace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(lRecipient, olFolderCalendar);
            lLog := Format('Logging in as different user (%s), created recipient for %s, GetSharedDefaultFolder folder path = %s',[AUserSMTP,lRecipient.Address,FCalendarFolder.FolderPath]);
            TSyncLogger.LogAlways(lLog);
         except
            on E:Exception do
            begin
               Result := false;
               TSyncLogger.LogError(Format(sErrOpenGedeeldeAgenda,[AUserSMTP]));
            end;
         end;
      end
      else   // ... otherwise open default calendar folder 
      begin
         FCalendarFolder := FNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar);
         TSyncLogger.LogDetail('Opened default calendar folder, folder path = ' + FCalendarFolder.FolderPath);
      end;
   end;
   FOleInitialized := Result;
   if Result then TSyncLogger.LogDetail('Connected to Outlook') else TSyncLogger.LogAlways('Connection to Outlook failed');
end;
```

**Any ideas/suggestions what to do?**

Additional info:

- Outlook 2007 connected to Exchange 2013 RTM, under Win7-64
- I have several mail profiles set up for this computer, the one for connecting to Exchange 2013 is set up as the default profile that Outlook starts with. Every time Outlook starts (also from code) I get prompted for the password.

Comment: From the first glance I can spot general language mismatch.

Answer (score -1):

Keep in mind that the categories are stored on the per store basis. Do both items come from the same store? Or is one of them residing in a delegate mailbox?

Comment: This is all one user. As I wrote in the code the part *Open shared calendar for different user* does not apply in my test case.

Comment: Do you see the correct categories on the MAPI level? Using OutlookSpy, go to the calendar folder, click IMAPIFolder button, go to the "Associated Contents" tab, locate the message with PR_MESSAGE_CLASS == "IPM.Configuration.CategoryList", double click on it, locate the PR_ROAMING_XMLSTREAM property.