# Using Outlook Contacts In Delphi XE7

Tags: delphi, outlook

I am trying to get a list of all outlook contacts using delphi.

I found a couple of examples, all seemed to be outdated or flawed.

Currently I have the following code, but when I excecute the command at runtime I get the below error:

**Code:**

```
procedure Tinvite_friends.BitBtn2Click(Sender: TObject);
const
  olFolderContacts = $0000000A;
var
  outlook, NameSpace, Contacts, Contact: OleVariant;
  i: Integer;
begin
  Try
   outlook:=GetActiveOleObject('Outlook.Application');
  Except
    outlook:=CreateOleObject('Outlook.Application');
  End;
  NameSpace := outlook.GetNameSpace('MAPI');

  Contacts := NameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderContacts);
  for i := 1 to Contacts.Items.Count do
  begin
    Contact := Contacts.Items.Item(i);
    {now you can read any property of contact. For example, full name and
     email address}
    ShowMessage(Contact.FullName + ' <' + Contact.Email1Address + '>');
  end;

  Outlook := UnAssigned;
end;
```

**Error Message:**

```
Project appname.exe raised exception class EOLeSysError with message 'Invalid class string'.
```

The project does not get passed the below code before throwing the error.

```
Try
 outlook:=GetActiveOleObject('Outlook.Application');
Except
 outlook:=CreateOleObject('Outlook.Application');
End;
```

Is there an effective way to get a list of all contacts from outlook imported to a memo for example?

Comment: On which line exactly is the error triggered?

Comment: Hi @TomBrunberg as soon as the command starts `outlook := CreateOleObject('Outlook.Application');`

Comment: I can not reproduce the error here. You do have outlook installed? Which version?

Comment: @TomBrunberg Yes I have outlook installed, Outlook 2013. is there supposed to be certain conditions? For example, outlook must be closed/open etc?

Comment: Marcel, I'm using Outlook2007, usually MS has been very good in maintaining backwards compatibility. I guess you need to check MS docs that the names are correct. Sorry for not being able to help more at this time.

Comment: @TomBrunberg No worries, If you see anything I may be missing, it would be a great help :)

Comment: One more question: is your Outlook 64 bit and your Delphi app 32 bit? If so, could you try with making a 64 bit Delphi app.

Comment: @TomBrunberg both are 64bit.

Comment: @Tom it's an out of proc server

Comment: @David Yes, I realized later that bitness is insignificant because of this.

Comment: what version of Outlook 2013 is it? I have issues with the Starter edition in the past not being able to interface with my apps

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's case sensitivity? I test for `outlook.application`:

```
const
  scxOutlookApp = 'outlook.application';
  scxNameSpace  = 'MAPI';

function TDataModuleSyncOutlook.ConnectToOutlook(AUserSMTP: String = ''): Boolean;
var
   lRecipient,
   lVar      : OleVariant;
   lLog,
   lLoginSMTP: String;
begin
   Result      := false;
   FWasCreated := False;  // Breakpoint 'Ignore subsequent exceptions' 
   try
      FOutlookApp := GetActiveOleObject(scxOutlookApp);         // Application object
      Result := True;
   except
      try
         FOutlookApp := CreateOleObject(scxOutlookApp);
         FWasCreated := True;
         Result := True;
      except
         on E:Exception do TSyncLogger.LogError(E.Message);
      end;
   end;
   if Result then          // Breakpoint 'Handle subsequent exceptions' 
   begin
      FNameSpace := FOutlookApp.GetNamespace(scxNameSpace);
      // Solution from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18053110/retrieve-outlook-logged-in-user-smtp-address-after-connecting-through-ole/
      lLog := Format('Connected to Outlook; Application.DefaultProfilename: %s, Application.Name: %s, Application.Version: %s, NameSpace.CurrentProfileName: %s, NameSpace.ExchangeMailboxServerName: %s, NameSpace.Type: %s',
        [FOutlookApp.DefaultProfileName,
         FOutlookApp.Name,
         FOutlookApp.Version,
         FNameSpace.CurrentProfileName,
         FNameSpace.ExchangeMailboxServerName,
         FNameSpace.Type]);
      TSyncLogger.LogDetail(lLog);
      lVar := FOutlookApp.Session;                                   // NameSpace object for the current session
      if not VarIsClear(lVar) then lVar := lVar.CurrentUser;         // Recipient object for the currently logged-on user
      if not VarIsClear(lVar) then lVar := lVar.AddressEntry;        // AddressEntry object for the recipient
      if not VarIsClear(lVar) then lVar := lVar.GetExchangeUser;     // Returns an ExchangeUser object that represents the AddressEntry
      if not VarIsClear(lVar) then lVar := lVar.PrimarySmtpAddress;  // String representing the SMTP address for the ExchangeUser
      if not VarIsClear(lVar) then
      begin
         lLoginSMTP := FOutlookApp.Session.CurrentUser.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser.PrimarySmtpAddress;
         TSyncLogger.LogDetail('Primary Exchange SMTP address detected as: ' + lLoginSMTP);
      end
      else
      begin
         TSyncLogger.LogError(sErrNoExchangeAccount);
         DisConnectFromOutlook;
         Exit;
      end;
      if LowerCase(AUserSMTP) <> Lowercase(lLoginSMTP) then
      begin   // Open shared calendar if it's a different user
         lRecipient := FNameSpace.CreateRecipient(AUserSMTP);
         try
            FCalendarFolder := FNameSpace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(lRecipient, olFolderCalendar);
            lLog := Format('Logging in as different user (%s), created recipient for %s, GetSharedDefaultFolder folder path = %s',[AUserSMTP,lRecipient.Address,FCalendarFolder.FolderPath]);
            TSyncLogger.LogAlways(lLog);
         except
            on E:Exception do
            begin
               Result := false;
               TSyncLogger.LogError(Format(sErrOpenGedeeldeAgenda,[AUserSMTP]));
            end;
         end;
      end
      else   // ... otherwise open default calendar folder
      begin
         FCalendarFolder := FNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar);
         TSyncLogger.LogDetail('Opened default calendar folder, folder path = ' + FCalendarFolder.FolderPath);
      end;
   end;
   FOleInitialized := Result;
   if Result then TSyncLogger.LogDetail('Connected to Outlook') else TSyncLogger.LogAlways('Connection to Outlook failed');
end;
```

Notes:
1. This opens the default calendar for any user, but you would not need to go that far (besides, your issue is earlier)
2. TSyncLogger is our logging handler
3. `FOleInitialized, FWasCreated: Boolean; FOutlookApp, FNameSpace, FCalendarFolder: OleVariant;` are some private properties we maintain
4. Essential to this code is that it first does a `GetActiveOleObject` to catch a running instance of Outlook; if that fails it does a `CreateOleObject`

Comment: I tested in small caps but still the same error shows up... Can you possibly provide code a little closer to what I would need? It's difficult to figure out what I need from the code you posted.

Comment: See added note 4. You only need to go to opening the namespace, but your actual issue is earlier. There is something else that can be going on, but I'm not at work where I have the documentation, so I'll provide another answer next Monday.

Comment: I have added the code mentioned in note 4, but it still does not get passed the first lines of code... I am not sure if it may be an issue with the office 2013 and delphi xe7 combination

Comment: The other issue I can think of does not justify a separate answer, so I'll just make it a comment: what happens if (in Outlook) you go to Tools / Trust Center / Programmatic access, and set it to the third option "Never warn me about suspicious activity". It *should* only prevent a prompt, but who knows...

Comment: If I recall correctly nothing in Delphi is case-sensitive.

Comment: @FedericoRusso Whether Delphi is case sensitive is irrelevant. Are the Outlook Object model and OLE case insensitive? (Turns out they are not, e.g. 'Outlook.Application' works as well).