# What are my options to access Outlook data from Delphi?

Tags: delphi, outlook, delphi-xe8

TurboPower had an `OfficePartner` library to allow Delphi programmers to access Microsoft Outlook information. But a long time ago (before the year 2000, IIRC) TurboPower stopped `OfficePartner` development together with its other libraries and made everything public domain.

I'm using a couple of these abandoned libraries (like `AsyncPro`, `SysTools` and `Orpheus`) and am very happy with them. But unlike these I didn't manage to install `OfficePartner` under Delphi XE8. It looks like the files from the [latest release on SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tpofficepartner/) (1.64) date back from Delphi 7 days in 2003. It's hardly surprising that the runtime package won't compile anymore under XE8.

Has there still been worked on `OfficePartner` in recent years, in a SourceForge fork, or has the project completely been abandoned?

Comment: @downvoter: please tell me what's wrong with my question so that I can improve it.

Comment: I didn't downvote (although I've voted to close) because your question is off-topic here. See [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), particularly #4 in the section with the numbered list, which says in part *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.*.

Comment: I was curious how hard it was to port to Delphi 10 Seattle, and the answer is, it took me 2 minutes.  Changed a few Pointers to nativeInt, and voila. Don't know if it works, but it compiles.   https://bitbucket.org/wpostma/tpofficepartner

Comment: @Warren Why would you change pointer to nativeint?

Comment: To match the signature changes in the RTL, I believe something changed in a few methods in ActiveX or ComObj

Comment: @KenWhite: I'm not asking for subjective opinions, I'm asking for objective facts: is the OfficePartner project still alive? Furthermore, while I share your concerns about spam, a typical characteristic of spam is that it is unasked for. When it's a reply to a request it's information, not spam.

Comment: @Warren: I looked into it myself, but kept having compiler errors, and besides I'm reluctant to play with code I don't completely understand. Thanks for your changes. It compiles alright, but the Tool Palette only shows 8 components, and according to the reference guide and help file there should be (a lot) more. Also, what happened to the designtime and runtime packages? Thanks a lot anyway :-)

Comment: @Joris *Are there other packages to interface with Outlook, preferably free?* This is pretty much a canonical example of of topic here. You'd be far better off asking such a question at delphi devs group of google+.

Comment: The guidelines are not established by me. :-) The part of your question asking if OfficePartner is still alive is marginal; the extension that asks for other possibilities (which you've since removed) was not, and that part is what I was addressing. If you have issues with the guidelines here, post a request at [meta] (after researching to see if it's been asked before) asking for them to be changed. Spam as you're referring to it is email; the problem here is spam posting of links to products and other garbage, and it's an actual problem that the rule here is meant to help prevent.

Comment: IOW, because you ask for it here does not mean it's acceptable here; it is *not*, and it is *expressly not* according to the site guidelines. You don't get a pass just because you want one.  :-) The guidelines I linked don't provide that exception.

Comment: This stuff belongs on a forum not here. I'd be in favor of deleting the whole thing.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply import the Outlook Object Model type library (Component | Import Component | Import a Type library) and use its various objects.

What exactly are you trying to do that OOM does not directly support?

Comment: I found a type library "Microsoft Office 16.0 Object Library", I guess that's what you mean? Is there any documentation on this? Would be handy for an `interface` section 17400 lines long :-). Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Create an instance of the Outlook.Application object using either the autogenerated coclass or using CreateOleObject function and go from there. As for OOM in general, it is not Delphi specific - start with  https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms268893(v=vs.110).aspx. You can also play with OutlookSpy (http://www.dimastr.com/outspy/) to see the live OOM objects and the data they expose.

Comment: @JorisGroosman: Documentation for the Outlook Object Model (and thus the type library) can be found at Microsoft. A Google search for *Outlook Object Model* should locate a link to it.

Comment: Documentations is part of MS Office itself. Just look into VBA (Visual Basic for Applications) documentation of it, part of that docs are description of "office object model", which actually is COM iDispatch interfaces you see in that file - just they are described in VBA syntax there, not Delphi syntax, but that is not that important.

Comment: Example of creating an Outlook instance in [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34566612/512728)

Answer (score 0):

You can Use Ole Api 
I Have Done Sending Email With Ole Api And OutLook before

```
 Outlook := GetActiveOleObject('Outlook.Application');
NmSpace := Outlook.GetNamespace('MAPI');
NmSpace.Logon('', '', False, False);
Outlook.ActiveExplorer().CurrentFolder = 'inBox';
Outlook.ActiveExplorer().CurrentFolder.Display();
```

Comment: You are connecting to an existing instance of Outlook (GetActiveOleObject). Your code will fail if Outlook is not already running. Always use CreateOleObject - Outlook is a singleton, you will get the running instance if it is already running.