# Cross-domain issue logging in to shared Outlook calendar folder?

Tags: delphi, outlook, calendar

This is the code with which we start Outlook and open a shared calendar folder for a user defined by primary SMTP address AUserSMTP:

```
const
  scxOutlookApp = 'outlook.application';
  scxNameSpace  = 'MAPI';
  olFolderCalendar  = $00000009;  // Outlook default calendar folder

function TDataModuleSyncOutlook.ConnectToOutlook(AUserSMTP: String = ''): Boolean;
var
   lRecipient,
   lVar      : OleVariant;
   lLog,
   lLoginSMTP: String;
begin
   Result      := false;
   FWasCreated := False; 
   try
      FOutlookApp := GetActiveOleObject(scxOutlookApp);
      Result := True;
   except
      try
         FOutlookApp := CreateOleObject(scxOutlookApp);
         FWasCreated := True;
         Result := True;
      except
         on E:Exception do TSyncLogger.LogError(E.Message);
      end;
   end;
   if Result then
   begin
      FNameSpace := FOutlookApp.GetNamespace(scxNameSpace);
      // From http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18053110/retrieve-outlook-logged-in-user-smtp-address-after-connecting-through-ole/
      lLog := Format('Connected to Outlook; Application.DefaultProfilename: %s, Application.Name: %s, Application.Version: %s, NameSpace.CurrentProfileName: %s, NameSpace.ExchangeMailboxServerName: %s, NameSpace.Type: %s',
        [FOutlookApp.DefaultProfileName,
         FOutlookApp.Name,
         FOutlookApp.Version,
         FNameSpace.CurrentProfileName,
         FNameSpace.ExchangeMailboxServerName,
         FNameSpace.Type]);
      TSyncLogger.LogDebug(lLog);
      lVar := FOutlookApp.Session;                                   // NameSpace object for the current session
      if not VarIsClear(lVar) then lVar := lVar.CurrentUser;         // Recipient object for the currently logged-on user
      if not VarIsClear(lVar) then lVar := lVar.AddressEntry;        // AddressEntry object for the recipient
      if not VarIsClear(lVar) then lVar := lVar.GetExchangeUser;     // Returns an ExchangeUser object that represents the AddressEntry
      if not VarIsClear(lVar) then lVar := lVar.PrimarySmtpAddress;  // String representing the SMTP address for the ExchangeUser
      if not VarIsClear(lVar) then
      begin
         lLoginSMTP := FOutlookApp.Session.CurrentUser.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser.PrimarySmtpAddress;
         TSyncLogger.LogDebug('Primary Exchange SMTP address detected as: ' + lLoginSMTP);
      end
      else
      begin
         TSyncLogger.LogError('No Exchange Server account found in Outlook');
         DisConnectFromOutlook;
         Exit;
      end;
      if LowerCase(AUserSMTP) <> Lowercase(lLoginSMTP) then
      begin   // Open shared calendar if it is a different user
         lRecipient := FNameSpace.CreateRecipient(AUserSMTP);
         try
            FCalendarFolder := FNameSpace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(lRecipient, olFolderCalendar);
            lLog := Format('Logging in as different user (%s), created recipient for %s, GetSharedDefaultFolder folder path = %s',[AUserSMTP,lRecipient.Address,FCalendarFolder.FolderPath]);
            TSyncLogger.LogDebug(lLog);
         except
            on E:Exception do
            begin
               Result := false;
               TSyncLogger.LogError(Format('Cannot open shared calendar for %s',[AUserSMTP]));   // <== error here
            end;
         end;
      end
      else   // ... otherwise open default calendar folder 
      begin
         FCalendarFolder := FNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar);
         TSyncLogger.LogDebug('Opened default calendar folder, folder path = ' + FCalendarFolder.FolderPath);
      end;
   end;
   FOleInitialized := Result;
   if Result then TSyncLogger.LogDebug('Connected to Outlook') else TSyncLogger.LogAlways('Connection to Outlook failed');
end;
```

We have an issue at a company that changed domain names, and I *think* that is the reason:

- Initially `user@olddomain.com` had granted editor access to `admin@olddomain.com` for their calendar (or the administrator had taken access).
- The company changed name and users primary SMTP addresses were changed from `@olddomain.com` to `@newdomain.com`.
- The code runs on a machine where `admin@olddomain.com` is still the logged in user, so Outlook starts with that account.
- When `admin@olddomain.com` starts Outlook, he can edit and delete appointments in the calendar of `user@newdomain.com`.

However, our code gives the 'Cannot open shared calendar' error (see 'error here') when we call the above procedure with either `user@olddomain.com` or `user@newdomain.com`.

While debugging the issue with an admin, he changed the primary SMTP for our test user back to `user@olddomain.com`, but the code still failed.

Questions:

- Can anyone confirm that my suspicion of a cross-domain issue is correct? Does this sound familiar?
- Could it be that our opening the default olFolderCalendar no longer is the correct way (because of the domain name change)?
- Other things that are suspect in the code?
- Other things that we could test or try to make this work?

Two things just cross my mind while writing this and I have not tested/verified them yet:

- I am assuming that `admin@newdomain.com` is now also the primary SMTP for admin, like everyone else.
- What if the Outlook profile on that machine is changed so that `admin@newdomain.com` starts Outlook?

Comment: Can you open that folder in Outlook (File | Open | Other User's Folder)?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko Is that different from opening the calendar for that user (my 4th bullet point)?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "he can edit and delete appointments in the calendar of user@newdomain.com". How is that folder opened?

Comment: Sorry I don't know, they were already present in the Outlook interface under 'People's calendars'. I'm assuming via 'Open a shared calender', but he may not even remember himself. But I can ask in a next (remote) debug session.